# form with Get method cancels jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, date

I am using Jquery and it is working perfectly until i submit a form using Get Method.

I am trying to get information between 2 dates. Here is my code:

**date.php:**

```
......

$date1 = $_GET['date1'];
$date2 = $_GET['date2'];
echo"<Form method='get' action=''>
<label>From: </label> <input class='date' id = 'date1' type='date' name='date1' size='9' value = '$date1'></input>
<label>To: </label> <input class='date' id = 'date2' type='date' name='date2' size='9' value = '$date2'></input> <br/> ";

echo "<input type='submit' class = 'center' value='submit' name='submit'>";
echo'</Form>';

if($date1 != '' && $date2 != '' ){
report($date1,$date2);
}
......

<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-ui.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/ui.js'></script> //my jquery functions

......
```

**ui.js:**

```
$('.date').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});

function toggleReport(table){   
$('#'+table).toggle('slow').colSpan = 3;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my GET method in my form?
should i use ajax instead? if i should, how do i use Get in ajax? until now i only used ajax with post method

THANKS!!!

***EDIT:***
it seems that it this whole thing wasn't my problem, something in my php is the problem.

I really got confused, i updated the date.php file above

Here is the report function:

```
function report($date1,$date2){

 $id = $_SESSION['id'];
 $techs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TECHS WHERE COMP_ID = '$id'")
 or die(); 
 $comps = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM COMPS WHERE COMP_ID = '$id'")
 or die(); 


  echo '<h1>Technicians</h1>';
  //tech Table
  echo "<table id='center'><tr><th id='hello'>Tech</th><th id='hello'>jobs</th><th    id='hello'></th></tr>";

 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $techs ))  
{
$name = $info['Name'];
$jobs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM JOBS WHERE COMP_ID = '$id' AND Technician = '$name' AND Date >= '$date1' AND Date <= '$date2' ORDER BY Date ASC") or die(); 
    $data = mysql_fetch_array( $jobs );

$number = mysql_num_rows($jobs);
if($number>'0'){
$name_st = remove_spaces($name);
$name_st.= '_t';
echo "<tr><td>$name</td><td>$number</td><td><img onclick='toggleReport(\"$name_st\");' src='images/report.png' border='0' alt='View report' title='View report'>
    </td></tr>";

    echo"
    <tr><td colspan='3' style='width:99%;' id='$name_st'  >
    <table >
        <th id='hello'>invoice</th><th id='hello'>Job ID</th><th id='hello'>Company</th><th id='hello'>Date</th><th id='hello'>Address</th><th id='hello'>Tech %</th><th id='hello'>Total</th><th id='hello'>Parts</th><th id='hello'>Company Parts</th><th id='hello'>Cash</th><th id='hello'>CC</th><th id='hello'>Check</th><th id='hello'>Fees</th><th id='hello'>Addt. Fees</th><th id='hello'>Company Balance</th><th id='hello'>Tech Balance</th><th id='hello'>Profit</th>

        ";
         $job = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM JOBS WHERE COMP_ID = '$id' AND Technician = '$name' ORDER BY Date ASC") or die(); 

        while($j = mysql_fetch_array( $job )){
            echo "<tr><td>".$j['invoice'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['jobID'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['Company'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['Date'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['Address'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['Tech_per'].'%</td>'.'<td>'.$j['Total'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['parts'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['comp_parts'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['cash'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['cc'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['check'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['fees'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['addt. fees <br> need to fix'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['comp_total'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['tech_total'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['profit'].'</td></tr>';
        }


        echo"
    </table></td></tr>";

}
  }
 echo '</table>';
 echo '<h1>Companies</h1>';
  echo "<table id='center'><tr><th id='hello'>Companies</th><th id='hello'>jobs</th><th   id='hello'></th></tr>";

   while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $comps ))  
 {
 $name = $info['name'];
 $jobs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM JOBS WHERE COMP_ID = '$id' AND Company = '$name' Date >= '$date1' AND Date <= '$date2'  ORDER BY Date ASC") or die(); 
    $data = mysql_fetch_array( $jobs );

$number = mysql_num_rows($jobs);
if($number>'0'){
$name_st = remove_spaces($name);
$name_st.= '_d';
echo "<tr><td>$name</td><td>$number</td><td><img onclick='toggleReport(\"$name_st\");' src='images/report.png' border='0' alt='View report' title='View report'>
</td></tr>";

    echo"
    <tr><td id='$name_st' class = 'hidden' colspan='3'>
    <table >
        <th id='hello'>invoice</th><th id='hello'>Job ID</th><th id='hello'>Company</th><th id='hello'>Date</th><th id='hello'>Address</th><th id='hello'>Comp %</th><th id='hello'>Total</th><th id='hello'>Parts</th><th id='hello'>Company Parts</th><th id='hello'>Cash</th><th id='hello'>CC</th><th id='hello'>Check</th><th id='hello'>Fees</th><th id='hello'>Addt. Fees</th><th id='hello'>Company Balance</th><th id='hello'>Tech Balance</th><th id='hello'>Profit</th>

        ";
         $job = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM JOBS WHERE COMP_ID = '$id' AND Company = '$name' ORDER BY Date ASC") or die(); 

        while($j = mysql_fetch_array( $job )){
            echo "<tr><td>".$j['invoice'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['jobID'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['Company'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['Date'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['Address'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['Comp_per'].'%</td>'.'<td>'.$j['Total'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['parts'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['comp_parts'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['cash'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['cc'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['check'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['fees'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['addt. fees <br> need to fix'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['comp_total'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['tech_total'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$j['profit'].'</td></tr>';
        }


        echo"
    </table></td></tr>";

   }
 }
 echo '</table>';


}
```

Comment: How do you submit the form? When does the `action` get set?

Comment: I use the same file, it is a php file so i just submit it and reload once the user hits submit, then it just cancels all my js

Comment: Where's the jquery? If you're submitting the page to itself, changing your design to work with Ajax would probably take a fair deal of work. If you have experience with jQuery ajax's `$.post` or `$.ajax`, you shouldn't have a problem doing it with the `get` method.

Comment: What do you do with Jquery that crashes after submitting? just to clean a bit your code insert <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?> inside the action, this also submits the page to itself. Also write <form> instead of <Form>, instead of </input> close the opening tag like this <input name=.......... />

Comment: this is all of my js $('.date').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});

Comment: I updated my question with more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Your form has a blank `action` attribute:</s>

```
<Form method='get' action=''>
```

You need to put the URL you want to submit to in there, e.g., to submit back to the same 'date.php' page:

```
<form method='get' action='date.php'>
```

(I am assuming you are not trying to set it from JS because you said in a comment that "all" of your JS is a single statement that initialises your datepicker controls. If that is not the case please update your question to show all of the JS code related to the form.)

**EDIT:** Sorry, I think I misunderstood the problem. I thought you meant that the form wasn't working properly. If you're saying that your JS isn't working properly it is probably because it is running before the page has loaded. Within your ui.js file try wrapping your JS in a document ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.date').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
});
```

Having said that, if you are submitting the page back to itself then Ajax would be a reasonable alternative.

> "how do i use Get in ajax?"

Look at the [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) doco - apparently "GET" is actually the default for the `type` parameter.

Comment: i changed it to 


<form method='get' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>'>
  and it still doesnt work, i have no idea why, but it seems to not load my js

Comment: i updated my question, i will try your suggestion right now and tell you if it worked, thanks for your help!

Comment: I just tried you suggestion with wrapping my code, it doesn't seem to make any changes.. im pretty sure that my problem is my php, i just tried to run my webpage without the **report** function and my js worked perfectly. there might be something in there.. i have to go over it.